# Unloading scenes still makes the audio continue + Random doesn't work right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code is meant to make the scenes switch and unload the last scene. This is working, but when pressed on random it isn't working correctly.

Also the sound isn't unloading so I think there is an error with the unloading of the scenes.

The problem: When scenes unload sound keeps going + When random is pressed no other scene can be loaded afterwards.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;



public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int _sceneCounter = 0;
    private Scene _lastScene;

    void Awake() {
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("1", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) 
        {
            if (_sceneCounter != 0) {
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("1", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                _sceneCounter = 0;
                _lastScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("1");
                SceneUnloader();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            if (_sceneCounter != 1) {
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("2", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                _sceneCounter = 1;
                _lastScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("2");
                SceneUnloader();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            if (_sceneCounter != 2) {
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("3", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                _sceneCounter = 2;
                _lastScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("3");
                SceneUnloader();
            }

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            if (_sceneCounter != 3) {
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("4", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                _sceneCounter = 3;
                _lastScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("4");
                SceneUnloader();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            if (_sceneCounter != 4) {
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("5", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                _sceneCounter = 4;
                _lastScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("5");
                SceneUnloader();
            }
        }


         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
         {
            if (_sceneCounter != 5) {
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("6", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                _sceneCounter = 5;
                _lastScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("6");
                SceneUnloader();
            }
         }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            if (_sceneCounter != 6) {
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("7", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                _sceneCounter = 6;
                _lastScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("7");
                SceneUnloader();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 6));
            _sceneCounter = 7;
        }

    }

    private void SceneUnloader() {
        if (_lastScene != null) {
            SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(_lastScene);
            Debug.Log("SceneUnloaded");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although i have no real unity3d knowledge: shouldn't you unload the scene before loading a new one?

Comment: I believe it does so in the private void SceneUnloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your random scene load, you forgot add mode

```
LoadSceneMode.Additive
```

So you scene loads in single mode

Also: keep in mind you receive int in random range, so it will load Scene number in build settings. Call

```
UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 6).ToString()
```

to load by scene name

And in your random loader you do not store

```
 _lastScene
```

and you fill

```
_sceneCounter
```

wrong. So you should do something like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
{
    // This can be cleaner, just for logic to not load current scene
    int randomScene = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 6);
    while (_sceneCounter == randomScene)
    {
        randomScene = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 6);
    }
    _sceneCounter = randomScene;            
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(_sceneCounter.ToString(), LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    _lastScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName(_sceneCounter.ToString());
    SceneUnloader();
}
```